# How stream AudioBuffer on Iphone?

Tags: iphone, typescript, stream

I get audio data from stream and i want to play audio on iphone Safari. iPhone dont play any sound, but when i allow meadiaDevice with audio, iPhone played audio. Can i play data without allow meadiaDevice ?

My code:

```
    var audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var audioCtx = new audioContext();
    var data = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(result.audioData)
    var source = new AudioBufferSourceNode(audioCtx);
    source.buffer = data;
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.start(0);
```

I must allow media

```
   await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }) for the stream. If you don't allow it, the stream will stop